# rvm using /after_cd_bunlder vs --binstubs. How are these different?

Tags: rvm

How are the outcome of these two methods different? Why use one over the other? I believe they both end up enabling you to issue 'rake' or 'rspec' without the preceeding 'bundle exec". My guess - with method 1 you only have to do this once, and then on ALL new rails project for the rvm ruby version will automatically have the desired feature ( as explained above)?

Method 1:

```
rvm get head && rvm reload
chmod +x $rvm_path/hooks/after_cd_bundler
bundle install --binstubs
```

OR

Method 2:

```
bundle install --binstubs
```

If found this documentation, but it did not help me understand which method to use. I looked on http://rvm.io and found intergration/bundler and /workflow/hooks.

The is code for after_cd_bundler (but I cannot post anymore links due to stackoverflow.com limitations on me)

Answer (score 0):

This are not two different methods, this is one method and it is described in more detail here: http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/15346721484/use-bundlers-binstubs

If you are using RVM then you do not need any of this, using `--binstubs` requires adding to `PATH` - which is big security risk if used from project directory, RVM comes with `rubygems-bundler` gem preinstalled which does the automatic loading of `bundler` (no need for `bundle exec`), you can find more details about the gem here: https://github.com/mpapis/rubygems-bundler#readme

*I am author of rubygems-bundler and maintainer of RVM.*

Comment: I will review the documentation and links YOU sent, and run some examples. Thank-you for responding and helping!<p>But I thought I found if when using rvm, I had to at least type in 'bundle --binstubs" in order to get the gem RSpec to work with just typing 'rspec' at the command line. But then I saw the METHOD 1, and wondered  why I would have to do that method, vs just doing METHOD 2.

Comment: as explained in my answer `rubygems-bundler` does all the work for you, no need for any extra steps, the books not always do it right, especially that everyone can write a book now-days and those materials might get out of date quite quickly - especially in ruby word.